# Cannot assign requested address error with bitcoin-abe

Tags: python-2.7, bitcoind, dogecoin-api

I have been playing around with [bitcoin-abe](https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe) for the last few days, getting it to load the dogecoin blockchain.  Everything works perfectly on my `localhost` and when I go to `http://localhost:2750` everything works fine.  Unfortunately, as soon as I move it to a live server with the following config:

```
dbtype sqlite3
connect-args doge.sqlite
port 2750
host SERVER_IP_ADDRESS
datadir = [{
        "dirname": "/home/ubuntu/.dogecoin",
        "chain": "Dogecoin",
        "code3": "DOGE",
        "address_version": "\u001e",
        "magic": "\u00c0\u00c0\u00c0\u00c0",
        "conf": "dogecoin.conf",
        "trim_depth": 40
        }]
commit-bytes = 100000
keep-scriptsig = false
int-type str
```

I get this error when I start up:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-198-38-95:~$ sudo python -m Abe.abe --config doge.conf 
Opened /home/ubuntu/.dogecoin/blocks/blk00022.dat
Abe initialized.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Abe/abe.py", line 2169, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Abe/abe.py", line 2165, in main
    serve(store)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Abe/abe.py", line 2047, in serve
    httpd = make_server(args.host, port, abe)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 144, in make_server
    server = server_class((host, port), handler_class)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 408, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 48, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
    SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 419, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I was asleep at the helm.  I just needed to use `0.0.0.0` as the host.